# EF Core “Group By could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.”

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am running a simple query against a SQL Server database using Entity Framework Core, however the `GroupBy` is not being executed on the server, instead it is being executed locally.

Is there something I'm missing that will force the group by onto the server?

```
var cwRequests = await (from c in _dbContext.CompanionSiteAccessRequests
                        group c by c.CustomerId into g
                        join cr in _dbContext.CrmDataSync
                                on g.Key equals cr.EntityId
                        where cr.EntityType == EntityType.ResourceRequest
                              && cr.IsRecordSync == false
                        select new
                               {
                                    CustomerId = g.Key,
                                    CWRequests = g.Where(s => s.RequestStatus == Bloomsbury.Domain.Customers.CustomerCompanionSiteAccessRequestStatuses.Approved)
                                                 .ToList(),
                                    CrmDataSync = cr
                               }).ToListAsync();
```

I want to get a list of customers with a collection of requests.

I get this warning:

> The `LINQ` expression `GroupBy([c].CustomerId, [c])` could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> The `LINQ` expression `join DataSync cr in value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable'1[Bloomsbury.Domain.CrmDataSync.DataSync]) on [g].Key equals [cr].EntityId` could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> The `LINQ` expression `where ((Convert([cr].EntityType, Int32) == 1) AndAlso ([cr].IsRecordSync == False))` could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> The `LINQ` expression `where (Convert([s].RequestStatus, Int32) == 2)` could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: After group by you cannot use navigation properties and cannot get list of items. Availaible only grouping key and aggregation result.

Comment: Please look at the large number of existing questions on this issue.